# Is there a way to deprecate a property which moved to another prefix?

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to spring-boot. I wonder if there is a way to deprecate a property which moved to another prefix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@DeprecatedConfigurationProperty` on the getter should be sufficient. That will cause the annotation processor to note that the property is deprecated in the metadata that's consumed by IDEs.